# Conditional expectation formula

Tags: probability

can I get an explanation why the following is the formula for conditional expectation? $$ E(X|Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$$

Comment: By substituting $X\,|\,Y$ into the definition of expectation for univariate continuous random variables - $E(X)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}xf_X\,dx$.

Comment: But $f_{X|Y}(x|y) $ is something like a function of two variables

Comment: @matt It is, so you would have $E(X\mid Y)$ to be a function of $y$, which make sense since $E(X\mid Y=y)$ is a scalar for any constant $y$.

Comment: Sorry about above, I mean $E(X\mid Y)$ is a function of $Y$, i.e. A random variable.

Comment: To make a clarification, the formula should be $E(X\mid Y=y)=\int_\mathcal{X} x f_{X\mid Y} (x\mid y)\mathrm dx$, which is a function of $y$. But if you are considering the conditional expectation given another **random variable**, then you shall get a random variable. To compute, just substitute $y$ by $Y$.

Comment: Regards @matt , I edited my point of view below. But some inputs may improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards @matt , I may not give full detail. Hope this will be useful.

-**In the discrete case**, the expectation $E(X)$ is the sum of each element (represents an event) in the random variable Sample Space $S$ multiplied by its corresponding probability. 
$$  S = \{ X, \: X = e_{1}, \: \: e_{2}, \:\: , .... \}  $$
$ e_{i} $ is a representation of the event (in a number). 
$$ E(X) = e_{1} P(X=e_{1}) + e_{2} P(X=e_{2}) + ....  $$
Now consider about Conditional Probability and with sets of events $X$ and $Y$ : the notation $X|Y$ , or $X|Y$ in particular means we are ***considering the problem only within a Sample Space $S_{Y}$***. We only consider events in $X$ that are subsets of $Y$, so $Y$ becomes the sample space. So :
$$ E(X|Y) = e_{1} P(X=e_{1}|Y) + e_{2} P(X=e_{2}|Y_{2}) + ....  $$
-**In the continuous case**, we cannot calculate probability at a point, but only probability density. So we use integral instead of summation and get 
$$ E(X|Y=e_{y}) = \int x f_{X|Y}(x, e_{y}) dx $$
with *the definition* : $$f_{X|Y}(x,e_{y}) = \frac{f(x,e_{y})}{f_{Y}(e_{y})} $$
so the ratio (or in continuous case : 'relative density') is with respect to $f_{Y}(e_{y})$. So we see the events in $X$ that are coincide with the event $\{Y=e_{y}\}$.

- Note that $f_{Y}(e_{y})$ is not the probability $P(Y = e_{y})$, but it does '**approximate**' it as an average. $$ f_{Y}(e_{y}) = \frac{F_{Y}(e_{y}+ \delta y) - F_{Y}(e_{y})}{ \delta y} $$ Similarly for the joint pdf $f(x,e_{y})$.
  Notice also the definition of conditional pdf $f_{X|Y}(x,e_{y})$ looks similar with the conditional discrete case :
  $$ f_{X|Y}(x,e_{y}) = \frac{f(x,e_{y})}{f_{Y}(e_{y})}, \: \: \: \: \: P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)} $$

Thanks, all the best.